# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null JAX-RS

Tags: java, angularjs, jax-rs

I'm developing a web application using JAX-RS, AngularJS, Spring Boot and Spring MVC.

I am looking to add a car in my database which must be unique. So I did this:

- Cars.java:

  ```
  @Entity  @Table(name = "idCars",uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name", "idAidCars"}))
      public class Actifs implements Serializable {

          @Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
          @Column(name="idCars")
          private long idCars;

          @Column(name="Name") 
          private String Name;
      }
  ```
- CarsRestController.java:

> ```
> @CrossOrigin("*")
> @RestController
> @RequestMapping(value="/Cars")
> public class CarsRestController {
>
> // Add car in DB
> @RequestMapping(value="/Add",method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
>   public Cars AddCars(@RequestBody(required=false) @Valid Cars cars){
>       return repository.save(cars); // object is NULL
>   }
>
> }
> ```

- AngularJS:

> ```
> $scope.AddCars=function(){
>  var dataObj = {
>                   name :  $scope.name  
>           };  
>   console.log("Name of car "+$scope.name) // BMW
>
> var res = $http.post("/Cars/Add", dataObj);
> res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>     $scope.message = data;
>     console.log("** "+JSON.stringify(data)); // Nothing displayed
> });
> res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>     alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
>   });     
> $scope.name='';
> };
> ```

- Html Form:

> ```
> <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" >
> <label for="name">Name Cars *:</label> 
> <input type="text" ng-model="name" required="required">   
> <button type="submit" ng-click="AddCars()"> Add Cars </button>
> </form>
> ```

After an add-on test I always have the object sent from angularJS to API rest is always NULL, I do not know why?

> Target object must not be null; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null

How to correct this problem?

- WebSecurityConfig

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebSecurity
  @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
  public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
              @Autowired
                protected void globalConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
               //auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("123").roles("USER");
                   auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                       .dataSource(dataSource)
                       .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                       .usersByUsernameQuery("select username as principal, password as credentials, etat as actived from utilisateurs where username=?")
                       .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username as principal, ur.nom_role as role from utilisateurs u inner join roles ur on(u.roles_id=ur.id_role) where u.username=?")
                       .rolePrefix("ROLE_");
               }
          protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

          http
                    .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(100).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false).expiredUrl("/Login");
                    http
                     .authorizeRequests()
                     .antMatchers("/images/**","/pdf/**","/Template/**","/Views/**","/MainApp.js","/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                     .antMatchers("/Cars/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
          .antMatchers("/Login").anonymous()
                     .anyRequest().authenticated()
                     .and()
                     .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                     .and()
                     .formLogin().loginPage("/Login").permitAll()
                     .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)  
                     .failureUrl("/Login?error=true")
                         .and()
                         .csrf()
                         .and()
                          .rememberMe().tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                          .tokenValiditySeconds(360000); 
          }
  ```

  Thank you,

Comment: Open the `Network` tab in browser console and check what payload is being sent.

Comment: I have refused access to the link: `http://localhost: 8080/App/Cars/Add` , however I logged in with an ADMIN account. I updated the post

Comment: I guess the api is hosted on another host different from where the request is being sent, look into CORS if this is it.

Comment: The problem when I access a `http://localhost:8080/App/Cars/ALL`, I have all the list of cars with no problem. Except that the addition requires access I do not know why?

Comment: Someone could help me, thanks